# Fourier transform of following equation

Tags: fourier-analysis

Say I have the following equation

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & \text{if} \;|x|,|y| \leq 1 \\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

What is the Fourier transform of this equation?

Comment: About usage: "Fourier transform of _function_" is usual, in your situation above.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions $|x|,|y|<1$ mean the integration from $-1$ to $1$ over $x$ and $y$ in the following integral
$$
g(k_x,k_y) = \int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 e^{ik_x x+ik_y y}\,dx\,dy.
$$

This integral is a multiplication of two simple 1-dimensional integrals

$$
g(k_x,k_y) = \bigg(\int_{-1}^1 e^{ik_x x}\,dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_{-1}^1 e^{ik_y y}\,dy\bigg) = \frac{4 \sin (k_x) \sin (k_y)}{k_x k_y}.
$$

Comment: An obvious but useful sanity check: The limit as $(k_x,k_y)\to(0,0)$ is just $4$ which is the same as the area enclosed in the $xy$-plane.